# Tricky Logic/Segment Problem?

Tags: probability, geometry

A stick of length 10 is broken in one place. Find the probability that the longer piece is at least twice as long as the shorter piece and no more than 5 longer than the shorter piece. I've tried systems of equations, graphing stuff, I can't get far on this one. The correct answer is 1/6, but I get 1/10. Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you show how you get 1/10, someone might spot an error that you can then avoid on future problems.

Comment: It was essentially guess and check, it wasn't an answer I came to with confidence

Comment: Not sure how you would "guess and check" a question like this. (Guessing is easy, checking is the tricky part.)

Comment: Yeah it was a desperate attempt at something, I would just come up with any number, say 6.5 and see if that fits the  criteria for the longer side, and kept doing it and I got a range of 6.5-7.5 that it works for, so 1/10 of the stick fits the criteria, 1/10

Comment: Ah, I see. That actually would work (at least sort of) if you had honed in on the range a little more tightly. The upper bound 7.5 is the correct maximum, and 6.5 is close to the minimum (it's actually a little too low: 6.5 < 2(3.5)). But the other problem was you divided by 10, as if any value 0 to 10 was equally likely; but since you were measuring the length of the _longer_ piece, only values in the range 5 to 10 are possible.

Comment: Just found the lower limit to be 20/3 I believe, possibly

Comment: Yes, that's the exact minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of developing intuition, I'll approach this with minimal
use of equations. In general, I think a solution like Théophile's that sets up well-constructed equations will more reliably get results.

The condition "at least twice as long" means the break cannot occur in the middle $1/3$ portion of the stick. The longer piece must have a length at least $20/3$, that is, at least $2/3$ of the entire stick.

The condition "no more than $5$ longer" means the break must be somewhere in the middle $5$ units of length of the stick.
Otherwise the break would leave more than $15/2$ units in the longer piece
and less than $5/2$ units in the shorter piece, which is a difference of more than $5.$

So out of all the places on the stick where the break might occur
(which I assume is equally likely along the entire length of the stick),
breaks anywhere within the $1/4$ of the length of the stick on either end will fail to meet the conditions, and so will breaks in the middle $1/3.$
The proportion of the stick that remains, where the conditions will be
satisfied, is
$$ 1 - \frac14 - \frac14 - \frac13 = \frac16. $$

Answer (score 2):

The lengths of the longer piece and shorter piece will be $5+x$ and $5-x$, respectively, for some $0 < x < 5$. If the longer piece is at least twice as long as the shorter, but no more than five units longer, then we have

$$2(5-x) \le 5+x \le 5 + (5-x),$$

which leads to

$$\frac53 \le x \le \frac52.$$

The probability that $x$ satisfies this condition is

$$\frac{\frac52-\frac53}5 = \frac16.$$

Comment: Did you mean to put the entire thing over 10 at the bottom, since the entire sick has length 10? Because the correct answer is 1/6

Comment: @NickBrown No, I meant 5! Consider that $x$ varies between 0 and 10, not 0 and 5. The answer to the question as you have phrased it is 1/3. It would be different if you asked, for example, what is the probability that the *left piece* is at least twice as long as the *right piece*, but no more than five times as long.

Comment: @DavidK Oh, I see. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @NickBrown It seems I misread the question at first—mea culpa. I've updated the answer, but note that the denominator didn't change; make sure you understand why it's 5 and not 10.

Comment: Okay I see what you're referring to now, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Let $L$ be the length of the longer, and $l$ be the length of the shorter piece.

1) $ 2l \leq L \leq 5l$ ;

2) $L + l = 10$.

Eliminating $l$ in these inequalities yields:

3) $6 \frac{2}{3}  \leq L \leq 8 \frac{1}{3}$.

Fix the stick horizontally, say, and put a ruler below (with length markings on it).

Now consider the sets of points:

$A$ =: { $x : 0 \leq x \lt 6 \frac{2}{3}$ }, $x$ representing the length of the stick measured from the left.

$P(A)$ stands for the probability of breaking a stick of length $ \lt 6 \frac {2}{3}$.

Ratios : $6 \frac {2}{3} : 3 \frac {1}{3} = 20 : 10$, yields

$P(A) = 2/3$.

$B$ := { $y : 0 \leq y \leq 8 \frac {1}{3}$ }, $y$ representing the length of the stick measured from the left.

Finding ratios: $8 \frac {1}{3} : 1 \frac { 2}{3} = 25 : 5 = 5 : 1$.

$P(B) = 5/6$.

The set $ B$ \ $A$ = { $z : 6 \frac {2}{3} \leq z \leq 8 \frac {1}{3}$}  represents the desired range of lengths.

4) $B = A \cup$( $B$ \ $A$), union of two disjoint sets.

$P(B$ \ $A) = P(B) - P(A)$.

With $P(B) = 5/6, P(A) = 2/3$, we get

$P(B$ \ $A) = 5/6 - 2/3 = 1/6$.

$Question: $

Assuming the stick not fixed at one end, is there a factor of 2, since the same reasoning applies to" the other end" which would double the probability?

Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I'm getting an answer of 1/3, can someone correct my mistake?

I'm taking a look at a range that can be cut. 
We know that at 1/6, it is the smallest we can cut, since anything else will produce a stick that is more than 5 times the other one
We also know that it can't be more that 5/6, for the same reason
The stick also has to be smaller than 1/3 and bigger than 2/3 because if it is in the middle, we would not have one that is at least twice the other.

Putting those together, we have:
$\dfrac{1}{6}\leq x\leq\dfrac{1}{3}$  or $\dfrac{2}{3}\leq x\leq\dfrac{5}{6}$

$2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}- \dfrac{1}{6}\right) = \dfrac{2}{6} = \dfrac{1}{3}$

Assuming the probability of selecting any point to cut is the same, the probability to cut based on the specific conditions is $\dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: I misread it the same way initially -- the mistake is that the longer stick can't be more than 5 units longer than the shorter one (rather than 5 times as long).